# Not able to Install Teamviewer on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, teamviewer

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS System and I am not able to install Teamviewer 10 and is throwing :

```
dependency not satisfiable lib32asound2
```

Have somenone worked on it before?

Answer (score 1):

First, download it:

wget http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb
Now you have 2 options. You can use gdebi (recommended) to solve the dependencies, or you can solve them yourself.

Gdebi method:

First, install gdebi:

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
In the same directory you downloade the .deb file just run:

sudo gdebi teamviewer_linux.deb
It will list the dependencies and install it with a y.

Answer (score 0):

How about his one liner?

```
cd ~/Downloads/ && wget http://downloadeu2.teamviewer.com/download/version_10x/teamviewer_10.0.37742_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i teamviewer* && sudo apt-get -y install -f
```

Open a Terminal and paste the command above into it. This should work for you!

What it does is change the current working directory to your Downloads folder, download the newest **Teamviewer 10** (32/64 bit) .deb file and installs it via `dpkg -i`. After the installation fails (because of the dependencies) it installs all dependencies and Teamviewer itself via `apt-get install -f` (the **-y** option automatically accepts any question with *yes*).